# Sigilless class attribute

Tags: object, syntax, raku

Although you can actually [itemize](https://docs.raku.org//language/contexts#Item_context) any kind of data structure to fit it into a scalar variable, sigilless variables might have some intrinsic value, since they are actually *shapeless*, to be used as class attributes. However, there seems to be no way to do so, `has \.a` does not work, `has .\a` either. A `has $!a` can probably cover most of what we could achieve with sigilless variables, but would there be an actual way to use them as attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's currently no way to have a sigilless attribute. It's also not, so far as I'm aware, currently under active consideration for inclusion in a future Raku version. The most obvious design considerations, were it to be proposed, would be:

1. The semantics of `my \foo = ...` are single static assignment. It's quite clear what that means on a lexically scoped symbol. It's less clear what it would mean in a class declaration, and how it would interact with the instantiation workflow. For example, there'd be no equivalent of the `:$!foo` signature syntax that can be convenient in `BUILD`/`TWEAK`.
2. The use of a twigil implies that it follows a sigil. The twigils without that are potentially ambiguous, depending on context. Further, it'd be odd to allow the `.` case only for the purpose of declaring that we want a sigilless attribute to get an accessor.
3. It would break the rule that you can always find access to the instance state by looking for a `!` twigil, which would be a pity.